# friggeri CV biblatex problem?

Tags: biblatex, biber, documentclass-writing

I am trying to compile the cv template given [here](https://github.com/afriggeri/CV)
I am using ubuntu 13.04, TeXStudio 2.5.2 and TeXLive 2012.

I set up texstudio to use `biber` to compile the `biblatex` entries and also modified the code provided by friggeri to use `biber` as the backend with the following code:

```
\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Line 120: Package keyval Error: sorting undefined ...rticle}{article
>   in peer-reviewed journal}

and as I try using this template to learn latex programming (I would like to make my own CV template) I am not able to find the mistake. I already googled quite a lot but was unable to find any solution to my problem

Comment: What is the difference?  You are only adding the option `backend=biber` to the class' original call..?  It should not make any difference.  What version of `biblatex` and `biber` are you using?

Comment: I agree with you. Problem is, i made this change to try to solve this problem which also appears in the original version without my modification.

Comment: If you can't even compile the original file (which I was able to do once I changed the default fonts), what about the versions of `biblatex` and `biber`?

Comment: Then if you can compile the files, there must be indeed a problem in my Tex distribution or Latex software.

As I pointed out, I am using Tex Live 2012 (full) on a Ubuntu 13.04 system. I don't know how to check further than that the versions of biblatex and biber.

Could you indicate me on which system you are running ?

Comment: TL 2012 (from TUG) on Ubuntu 12.10.  `texdoc biblatex` and `biber -v` in a terminal will give you the docs of the former and the version of the latter.

Comment: I made a clean install of my tex live distribution. Now I have tex live 2012 installed directly from the tex live website, not the package.

I deleted the backend option so that I have a similar situation to yours.

I have now the following messages error in texmaker 

line 120 Type 'article' not found
line 120 Empty bibliography

Whereas in the directory I have the .tex, .cls and .bib files from friggeri site.

Also I compile using the XeLateX command of texmaker 3.5.2

Comment: You have run `xelatex` at least once; but have you also run `biber` (i.e., `biber cv.bcf`)?  The normal sequence for biber+biblatex is: `*latex`, `biber`, `*latex`.  It is complaining that the bibliography is empty: 'line 120' of `cv.tex` is `\printbibsection{article}{article in peer-reviewed journal}`, which is a command defined in the `.cls` file.

Answer (score 3):

I battled a couple hours more and finally solved the problem, partly thanks to jon's idea to issue the commands manually.

For anyone who runs into the same problem, here is what I did.

1) Fresh install of texlive 2012 on Fedora 18, following this [link](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). This was already quite a struggle because some perl packages are not install. I advise the user to carefully read the error messages if any concerning perl. Then usually the problem is solved by issuing the command

**sudo yum install "perlPackageName**

2) I installed texMaker 3.5.2

3) I installed the required fonts for the class I am using namely Xits and Helvetica, Helvetica Neue and Helvetica Neue Lt Std. The installation was performed system wide. To perform a system wide installation, on fedora I did the following steps

3a. Download your font
3b. issue in a terminal the following command

**sudo nautilus /usr/share/fonts**

which will open a sudo browser in your system font directory. There, create directory with the font name (be careful, these names are the names you will use in your tex document to call the font) e.g. Helvetica Neue. Then issue in a terminal the following command

**fc-cache -fsv**

which will refresh the fonts list for the tex fontconfig package.

4) Then in a terminal, issue the following commands

**xelatex yourfile.tex**

**biber yourfile**

**xelatex yourfile.tex**

5) enjoy your latex pdf document.

This was my quest to make the above mentionned files working. Maybe there is a simpler way, maybe I did something wrong during the installation (although I don't think so).

I also came across multiple aside problems when performing this. For example, I installed texlive as sudo. So to run the texlive package manager I have to issue the following command

**sudo $(which tlmgr) --gui**

instead of just

**tlmgr**

Also, when installing my helvetica fonts, I let a "mac original font" directory inside the font directories placed in /usr/share/fonts. The xetex engine complained about the following error :
 ** ERROR ** Cannot proceed without the "native" font in /usr/share/fonts/Helvetica Neue/mac original font
deleting the abovemetionned directory solved the problem

I know there are multiple problems here but I think this thread can maybe help someone who runs in the same problems as I did