# Package keyval Error: sorting undefined

Tags: xetex, biber, key-value

Even at the risk of being this question closed as too localized or a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116575/friggeri-cv-biblatex-problem), I feel that it is relevant for people like me, using XeLatex and Biber for the first time...
I am using [Adrien Friggeri's CV template](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) but I always get the following error, after having tried everything:

```
 Package keyval Error: sorting undefined.
```

I have Texlive 2013 on Ubuntu 13.10 and Texmaker 4.0.3-2. I installed texlive-xetex 2013 from the repositories, and in the friggeri-cv.cls file I changed the Helvetica fonts and commented the line \setmathfont{XITS Math}.

I changed the Quick Build in Texlive to XeLaTex + view PDF. At the beginning it produced the pdf with only warnings and the Publications section empty. So I figured I would have to install biber(0.9.9 from the repositories as well).

Since I installed biber, I get the error above on Texmaker. I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116575/friggeri-cv-biblatex-problem) and the error persists. I do not know where the error comes from.

Apart from the usage of the (quite popular) Friggeri template, I guess that this can be a quite general problem that should be looked at. I would really appreciate some help. Many Thanks!

EDIT:
I am including a MWE kindly provided by @DavidCarlisle (below). The error still persists with such example.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\listfiles
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{aaa}{bb}
       {cc}

\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, keyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\printbibsection{misc}{other publications}
\printbibsection{report}{research reports}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE!

Comment: I am using the exact same files as in here (https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) except for the commented line and the helvetica fonts changed to arial in the .cls file

Comment: @DaniCee Yes, perhaps, but on TeX.SX, we like questions to be self-contained. Part of your job is to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It's the surest way to a quick and satisfactory answer.

Comment: I just downloaded the zip file, changed helvetica references to  arial, and arial bold and the math to \setmathfont{xits-math.otf} (xits is in tex-live you shouldn't have to comment it out but you may need to refer to the font file name) xelatex biber xelatex xelatex produced a pdf with no warnings. (texlive 2014 pretest)  so I assume you have an out of date file somewhere.

Comment: I have edited to include the MWE provided by @DavidCarlisle. The error still persists. Sorry for not including the MWE before, I thought by touching the original file I would include more errors. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced file works without error if I change the font references. You presumably have an out of date biblatex.

Cutting down the test file (as you should have posted) and adding `\listfiles` I get

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\listfiles
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{aaa}{bb}
       {cc}

\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, keyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\printbibsection{misc}{other publications}
\printbibsection{report}{research reports}

\end{document}
```

which produces a file list as follows, check the dates that you see on your system and updated packages as necessary.

```
 *File List*
friggeri-cv.cls    2012/04/30 CV class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/05/20 v4814 L3 programming layer (loader) 
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
expl3-code.tex    2014/05/20 v4814 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  xparse.sty    2014/05/05 v4740 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fixltx2e.sty    2014/05/13 v1.1q fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fontspec.cfg
unicode-math.sty    2013/05/04 v0.7e Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
l3keys2e.sty    2014/05/05 v4740 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2014/05/13 v1.1q fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-xetex.sty    
unicode-math-table.tex
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
 textpos.sty    2014/01/03 v1.7j
biblatex.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
 verbose.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authortitle.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 verbose.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 verbose.cbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 english.lbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
      cv.bbl
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
      cv.out
      cv.out
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
 ***********
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response, though with this MWE the error still persists, I don't get that file list.
I am going to edit my question to include the MWE. Sorry about it, I didn't want to touch the file so much in case other errors could show up.

Comment: @DaniCee the filelist is printed at end document normally even if you get an error if you type s so it scrolls on it should print the list in the end.

Comment: @DaniCee presumably if you delete `sorting=chronological,` it will not complain about that key and you should get the filelist

Comment: I do not see that file list anywhere...
If I remove all the 'sorting' instances from both the MWE.tex and the friggeri-cv.cls, I don't get errors, but I get a lot of warnings like:

Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex) with 'friggeri:2011:inria-00621065:2':
(biblatex) - Not overwriting existing field 'type' during aliasi
ng of entrytype 'techreport' to 'report' in entry 'friggeri:2011:inria-00621065
:2'.

Comment: I would like to solve the sorting error too, and understand where it comes from... any idea?

Comment: I made a system upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 and the error does not show up. However, made others do, of the form:

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name
l.1433 \endentry
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: I really do not understand the new errors, any idea where they can come from?

Comment: Have you deleted the old temporary files from the runs before you updated?

Comment: I'm completely desperate... I removed all the files and tried to compile from 0 using LuaLaTex + View PDF in TexMaker... I get no errors (lots of warnings though), but the resulting pdf is EMPTY....

Comment: What does it require and how do people that succeed with it compile it?

Comment: I found out that if I run LuaLaTex + View PDF in the TexMaker Quick Build, then run biber in the terminal and then LuaLaTex + View PDF in the TexMaker Quick Build again, it produces the publications (though there are still some warnings)... how could I do the biber part in TexMaker instead of the terminal?

Comment: @DaniCee: Depends on why it doesn't work in texmaker. If you simply didn't configure texmaker correctly you can change this. But it seems also to happen sometimes that somehow the call of biber from texmaker is blocked (by the OS, by some security settings or something similar).

Comment: I will regard this question as closed, as it seems it only needed to update all the relevant software. I will post another question on how to run biber on TexLatex. Many thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the *sorting* option for *printbibliography* from the **friggeri-cv.cls**. *.I.e.* replace

```
\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}
}
```

Also remove all uses of the *sorting* key from your TeX file.